# How to generate elixir code using protobuf files?

Tags: elixir, protocol-buffers

I found lots of libraries for defining protobuf messages and all but I couldn't find a way to generate elixir code using `.proto` files like an elixir compiler for protocol buffers. What does the community use for this?

Comment: You can generate files with [protox](https://github.com/ahamez/protox). Disclaimer: I maintain this library.

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution but I don't know what do you want with generated elixir code (you can disassembly from macro compiled beam files). I think the generated macro is enough for `protobuf` communication and you don't need any generated elixir code. Btw you can use the generated `beam` files manually (another ugly solution)

### My ugly solution

Add exprotobuf as a dependency to your project:

```rb
defp deps do
  [{:exprotobuf, "~> 1.2"}]
end
```

Then run `mix deps.get` to fetch.

Add exprotobuf to applications list:

```rb
def application do
  [applications: [:exprotobuf]]
end
```

You need a proto file for example `msg.proto` with this content:

```
    message Msg {
      message SubMsg {
        required uint32 value = 1;
      }

      enum Version {
        V1 = 1;
        V2 = 2;
      }

      required Version version = 2;
      optional SubMsg sub = 1;
    }
```

Create an elixir file e.g.: `./lib/messages.ex` with:

```rb
defmodule Messages do
  use Protobuf, from: Path.expand("msg.proto", __DIR__)
end
```

And then

```sh
iex -S mix
```

In iex console

```
iex(1)> tic_tac_toe = ("your app name in mix.exs -> project -> app")
iex(2)> f = "./_build/#{Atom.to_string(Mix.env)}/lib/#{tic_tac_toe}/ebin/Elixir.Messages.Msg.beam"
"./_build/dev/lib/tic_tac_toe/ebin/Elixir.Messages.Msg.beam"
iex(3)> {:ok, beam} = File.read(f)
{:ok,
 <<70, 79, 82, 49, 0, 0, 13, 132, 66, 69, 65, 77, 65, 116, 85, 56, 0, 0, 1, 144,
   0, 0, 0, 37, 19, 69, 108, 105, 120, 105, 114, 46, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103,
   101, 115, 46, 77, 115, 103, 8, 95, 95, 105, ...>>}
iex(4)> IO.inspect :beam_disasm.file(beam), pretty: true
```

I don't recommend the use of this solution. It's just for fun.

Use [exprotobuf](https://github.com/bitwalker/exprotobuf) or [protobuf](https://github.com/tony612/protobuf-elixir.git) they will create a macro from your `proto` files for best performance. There are some limitations.

UPDATE:
I didn't try it but the `readme.md` contains a "Generate Elixir code" section in [protobuf](https://github.com/tony612/protobuf-elixir.git) package.

UPDATE2:
I have tested it successfully. I compiled some `.proto` files based on "Generate Elixir code" section in [protobuf](https://github.com/tony612/protobuf-elixir.git)